# Voyager (Laravel): Exception while rendering read-blade with many-to-many relation

Tags: laravel, exception, many-to-many, relation, voyager

I've started to use [Voyager](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager) and I'm facing problems with resolving relations. I receive an exception whenever I try to view/read a database entry that contains a many-to-many relation to another table.

I have 2 tables, *tours* and *activities* that are related via an m to n relation, and an intermediate table *activity_tour*. I've prepared the tables for voyager as mentioned in the [docs](https://laravelvoyager.com/docs/0.11/#core-concepts-bread-relationships).

**Table tours:**
id | title | someOtherStuff | activities
where *id* is a string.

**Table activities**
id | someOtherStuff | tours
*id* is a string again. In the BREAD-builder menu, I've added

```
{
    "relationship": {
        "key": "id",
        "label": "title"
    }
}
```

to the *tours* column of the *activities* table.

The Activity-Model contains the following method to resolve the relation

```
public function tours(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Tour::class, 'activity_tour');
}
```

**Table activity_tour**
activity_id | tour_id

I receive the following [error](https://pastebin.com/aDheWGXN), whenever I want to view a specific Activity-entry. The code-part that causes the exception can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/05fx9pLA) (Corresponding file: *vendor/tcg/voyager/resources/views/bread/read.blade.php* - starting at line 51).

But whenever I want to edit an activity, all related tours are loaded and displayed correctly without any error.

**Versions**

- Database: 10.2.3-MariaDB Homebrew
- Laravel: 5.4
- Voyager: v0.11.10